# How to access data in Parse Server via Cloud Code?

Tags: apache, parse-platform, xmlhttprequest, parse-cloud-code

I try to make queries using the cloud code feature of our Parse server. Unfortunately we could not retrieve any data from the database. Our code looks as follows:

**main.js:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('test', function(request, response) {
var user = request.user;
var token = user.getSessionToken();
var query = new Parse.Query('Carpark');
query.first({ sessionToken: token }) // pass the session token to find()
.then(function(messages) {
response.success(messages);
}, function(error) {
response.error(error);
});
});
```

**index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: 'mongodb://parse-server:[...]@localhost:27017/[...]',
cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: '[...]',
masterKey: '[...], //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
serverURL: 'https://backend.[...]/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
publicServerURL: 'https://backend.[...]/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
}
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

//var basicAuth = require('basic-auth-connect');
//app.use(basicAuth('triveme', 'triveme'));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/parse', api);
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = 61004;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

**Example request from iOS-App:**

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "test", withParameters: nil) {
(response, error) -> Void in
if let response = response {
let result = response
print("Cloud data:", result )
}
if error != nil {
print(error ?? "default cloud function error")
}
}
```

**I don't get any feedback from server (no response and no error). What is a possible problem of my issue?**

Log request with verbose = 1:

```
REQUEST for [POST] /parse/functions/test: {} method=POST, url=/parse/functions/test, host=localhost:61004, accept=*/*, x-parse-session-token=[...], x-parse-application-id=[...].platform.dev2, x-parse-installation-id=[...], x-parse-os-version=10.2 (16D32), accept-language=en-us, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, x-parse-client-version=i1.14.2, user-agent=trive.park/8 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.4.0, x-parse-app-build-version=8, x-parse-app-display-version=1.0, x-forwarded-for=[...], x-forwarded-host=backend.[...], x-forwarded-server=backend.[...], connection=Keep-Alive, content-length=0,
```

Log Response:

```
4|trive-pa | error: Failed running cloud function test for user nZ76ZimELw with:
4|trive-pa |   Input: {}
4|trive-pa |   Error: {"code":141,"message":{"code":100,"message":"XMLHttpRequest failed: \"Unable to connect to the Parse API\""}} functionName=test, code=141, code=100, message=XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API",  user=nZ76ZimELw
4|trive-pa | error: Error generating response. ParseError {
4|trive-pa |   code: 141,
4|trive-pa |   message: 
4|trive-pa |    ParseError {
4|trive-pa |      code: 100,
4|trive-pa |      message: 'XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"' } } code=141, code=100, message=XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"
4|trive-pa | [object Object]
```

parse-server version: 2.2.23
self hosted on Apache Server
MongoDB

Comment: Have you tried it your server running locally? Also, do you notice that the function name you call is different than the one you declared in your main.js file?

Comment: The different function name is a copy and paste error, I fixed it... I have not yet tried to run the server locally.

Comment: I recommend doing it before deploying to the cloud - you might find debugging *much* easier. Please run the server with `VERBOSE=1` for better logs, and update us here so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you, the log output is added to the question.

Comment: Two questions that might help:

1) If you use `curl` to call the function, do you get anything back?
2) If you add some `console.log()` statements in the `query.find()` callbacks, do you see something?

Comment: Also, make sure that locally the `serverURL` parameters is pointing to the right address (`http://localhost: 61004/parse` I believe)

Comment: After some time I get the log response error code 141 (see in the main question). Can you say anything about this?

Comment: Yes, that your Cloud Code function is trying to call the query, but is failing to do so. I believe there is an error configuring serverUrl.

Comment: Because of your help I could fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! Would you mind answering your own question, so that people facing the same issue can also get help from you?